# How do I disable div animations onclick() using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a div which animates as soon as page loads. Then I have a button. After one clicks on this button I want to make a new div and animate it as it animated previous, but onclick() the first div also changes it's position. How should I do it to somehow disable animate effect on div which already animated.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="car"></div>
</div>
<button id="button">spawn new car</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var car = $('.car');
    car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
    car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);


    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(".wrapper").append('<div class="car"></div>');
        var car = $('.car');
        car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
        car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are u appending ? and why u recall the same div ?

Comment: IT's just like a parking lot. I press button a new car spawns and goes to empty parking space.

Comment: what you want to do is on button click newly spawned car div take the place of old car div right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want old car to move or disapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following way you can move only newly added div.

Add one temporary move class when you add and remove it after animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var car = $('.car');
    car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
    car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);


    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(".wrapper").append('<div class="car move">car</div>');
        var car = $('.move');
        car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
        car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);
        $(".car").removeClass('move');
    });
});
```

```css
.car{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="car">car</div>
</div>
<button id="button">spawn new car</button>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37rx1g3t/)**

Answer (score 1):

**As you said :**

> *"but onclick() the first div also changes it's position"*

Reason is you are assigning `animate` to `class` `car` and first `div` too has a class `car` thats the reason it changing position.

**Solution** will be give *dynamic and distinct* `class` or `id`

Random ID you can give like :

```
$("#button").click(function () {
        var id=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        $(".wrapper").append('<div class="car_"'+id+'></div>');
        var car = $(".car_"+id+"");
        car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
        car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I think but how should I do it ?

Comment: Can't spawn a new div. :(

Comment: @nika : did you try now ?

Answer (score 0):

It's animating because this new div is being created and pushing it further down the page. You could use an absolute positioning in order to hold it in place. But that might make the page look a bit rigid. I'd just add a smoothing effect to the buttons move.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var car = $('.car');
car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);


$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".wrapper .car").removeClass('car');
    $(".wrapper").append('<div class="car"></div>');
    var car = $('.car');
    car.animate({left:"+=367px"}, 2000);
    car.animate({top:"-=247px"}, 2000);
});
});
```

This will remove `car` class from current `div` and adds new `div` with `car` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dzob8n00/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var car = $('.car');
        car.animate({left:367, top:0}, 2000);


        $("#button").click(function () {
            $(".wrapper").append('<div class="car"></div>');
            var car = $('.car');
            car.animate({left:367, top:-1}, 2000);
        });
    });

    .car{
        border:1px #000 solid;
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        position:relative;
    }
```